# Homeomorphism lifting a covering map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $p : E \to X $ be a covering map, with $X$ path-connected and locally path-connected, and $E$ path-connected. (The local path-connectedness of $E$ follows.) Also, let $f$ be a homeomorphism of $X$. I want to determine whether there is a "homeomorphism" $g$ of $E$ such that $p \circ g = f \circ p$, that is, $g$ lifts $f$.

In my intuition, I think this is false (I first tried to prove the statement assuming true, but I got stuck.) However, I am having a hard time finding a counterexample. How do I have to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well $f\circ p$ factors through $g$ if and only if the image of $\pi_1(E)$ by the induced morphism is included in that of $\pi_1(E)$.

So you are right that it doesn't always happen. It *does* happen if $E$ is a universal covering (because $\pi_1(E) =0$), so in our example we have to chose a nonuniversal covering.

Here's one example : let $\mathbb R\times S^1 \to \mathbb T = S^1\times S^1$ be the standard covering and $f:\mathbb{T\to T}$ be the homeomorphism that switches coordinates : $f(z_1,z_2) = (z_2,z_1)$.

Then if it lifted, we would get a map $g:\mathbb R\times S^1\to \mathbb R\times S^1$ that satisfied $p\circ g = f\circ p$. Now look at $h(z) := pr_{\mathbb R}\circ g (0,z)$ : it's a map $S^1\to \mathbb R$ and it satisfies $\exp \circ h (z)  = z$, where $\exp : \mathbb R \to S^1$ is the standard covering map.

This is of course absurd.

Comment: I feel bad asking because I'm sure it's obvious:  where's the contradiction?

Comment: @Randall : There are tons of ways to see that $\exp : \mathbb R\to S^1$ does not have a section. You can use general covering space theory and the fact that $\mathbb R$ is connected; or you can use the specificity of the situation and for instance argue that a continuous map $S^1\to \mathbb R$ can't be injective (if it were, it would be a homeo onto its image, which must be a segment $[a,b]$)

Comment: Ah, the second bit makes the most sense to me (contradicts Borsuk-Ulam).  Got it.

Comment: It should be way simpler than Borsuk-Ulam : the image of that section is connected, so an interval, and compact, so a segment $[a,b]$. These are known not to be homeomorphic to $S^1$ (e.g. you can remove a single point and break connectedness, which can't happen in $S^1$)

Comment: how about using induced homomorphisms and the fact that R is contractible

Comment: Yes, that's another way to see it : as I said, there are tons of ways to show that this can't happen, and it's very standard (and intuitive)